# Обработать каждый вариант enum

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

Если `enum Oper` порядка 30 штук. Есть метод класса, которая принимает параметр `Oper` и работает с полями класса. Каждый случай обрабатывается по разному.

1. Какая реализация `someFuncX` быстрее?
2. Есть ли подводные камни в реализации через лямды-выражения?
3. Общие советы. Например знаю что если делать через switch, то IDE подсказывает, если не все возможные `enum` отработаны.
4. Имеет ли смысл делать `std::array` статическим для выигрыша скорости?
5. Тоже будет справедливым, если `enum Oper` будет длиною 300 элементов?

Пример кода:

```
class C {
    int someField;
    enum class Oper {
        op1, op2, /*...,*/ op30
    };
    void someFuncIf (Oper o) {
        if (o == Oper::op1) {
            ++someField;
            /* some code 1*/
        } else if (o == Oper::op2) {
            --someField;
            /* some code 2*/
        } /*else if { ... }*/
        else if (o == Oper::op30) {
            someField *= 2;
            /* some code 30*/
        } else {
            assert(false);
        }
    }

    void someFuncSwitch (Oper o) {
        switch(o) {
        case Oper::op1:
            ++someField;
            /* some code 1*/
            break;
        case Oper::op2:
            --someField;
            /* some code 2*/
            break;
        /*case ...*/
        case Oper::op30:
            someField *= 2;
            /* some code 30*/
            break;
        }
    }

    void someFuncLambda (Oper o) {
        auto op0 = [this] () { ++someField; /* some code 1*/ }; // для инициализации array. Не знаю как по другому.
        std::array<decltype (op0()), static_cast<uint>(Oper::cntOper)> array;
        array[static_cast<uint>(Oper::op1)] = [this] () { ++someField; /* some code 1*/ };
        array[static_cast<uint>(Oper::op2)] = [this] () { --someField; /* some code 2*/ };
       // ...
        array[static_cast<uint>(Oper::op30)] = [this] () { someField *= 2; /* some code 30*/ };
        array[static_cast<uint>(o)]();
    }
};
```

Comment: Обычно компиляторы довольно хорошо реализуют switch, применяя там как jmp-таблицы (самый самый быстрый способ, но недостаток - фрагментация, т.е. куча нулей если есть разрывы между swith) так и "двоичный" поиск.

Comment: Подозреваю, что, для получения хотя бы части ответов, вопрос стоит разбить на несколько.

Comment: Один из самых быстрых способов - массив функций. Если быстродействие критично - советую массив функций, аналогичен  jmp-таблицам, чуть медленнее из-за вызова, и при большом уровне фрагментации невыгодный.

Comment: Касательно if - этот способ в вашей реализации неприемлем, но, если построить дерево if по-принципу "двоичного поиска" и оптимизатор сократит "лишние" сравнения - то можно достигнуть хороших результатов.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо. Ответ на основной вопрос я получил.

Comment: Не думаю,что вопрос следует разбивать на несколько, возможно нужно переформулировать вопрос. По сути, вы хотите понять какой из методов лучше, думаю что это должно быть в одном вопросе.

Comment: тут у меня проблема еще и с лямбдой. Не смог понять как использовать лямбды-выражения в контейнере

Comment: В лямду задайте именованый тип через typedef. `typedef void (*MY_FN01)();  std::Map<Oper,MY_FN0>` map отработает медленнее чем массив функций, потому что, сначала будет поиск елемента в массиве, а потом вызов.

Comment: выдает две ошибки если через `typedef` делать: `'Oper' does not refer to a value` и `C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations`

Comment: typedef  - делается отдельно от class-пространства либо пространства функции. Т.е. вне `{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько методов, позволяющих сделать реализацию

1. Обычно компиляторы довольно хорошо реализуют `switch`, применяя там как jmp-таблицы (самый самый быстрый способ, но недостаток - фрагментация, т.е. куча нулей если есть разрывы между swith) так и "двоичный" поиск. Я советую использовать именно `switch` в большинстве функций выбора.
2. `if` подходит если, а)можно построить двоичное дерево поиска б)разброс между параметрами большой, в) разброс параметров можно описать легко-вычисляемой функцией или обьеденить в выражение, например все четные елементы, или все отрицательные, г)если мало условий. В большинстве случаев `if` даст не очень хорошие результаты, но в отдельных случаях (например вычислить в сколько бит можно записать число от 0 до 255 - можно строеным if) он даёт довольно хороший результат.
3. Можно задать массив функций. Массив функций работает чуть медленнее чем jmp-таблица, из минусов - нужна сплошная заполненность таблицы функциями на диапазоне перехода (эту проблему решает map). Несуществующие случаи прийдется заполнять либо пустой функцией (dummy), либо нулями - и отбрасывать дополнительным if. Если есть возможность построить такой массив - то он будет работать либо быстрее чем switch, либо почти одинаково (при условии что оптимизатор правильно реализует switch).
4. map - это массив ключ-значение. Вначале будет сделан поиск елемента по-ключу, а потом вызов функции. Поэтому будет работать немного медленне чем метод 3, и я думаю switch его победит по скорости (при наличии хорошего оптимизатора для вашей среды). В отдельных случаях этот метод может дать результаты лучше чем switch (если оптимизатор плохой) и if. Так же вопрос про оптимальность map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931890/what-is-more-efficient-a-switch-case-or-an-stdmap

Comment: я обновил ф-цию `someFuncLambda`. Теперь использую массив. Нужно ли делать его статик? или инициализация массива лямбда-выражениями это не очень затратно?

Comment: Добавьте `static const` что б компилятор не пересоздавал таблицу вызовов, и расположил её без пересчета в readonly секторе.

Comment: Попробуйте явную инициализацию http://cppstudio.com/post/9691/ у меня в моей среде не получилось. Я бы попробовал применить всётаки вариант 3 для задачи виртуальной машины, т.к. обработка будет легче.

Comment: Сложности с созданием и использованием контейнера для лямбд-выражений, поэтому эту часть вопроса убираю... и спасибо

Comment: Применить map вместо switch идея интересная "чисто технически", Возможно как это сделать оптимальнее - заслуживает отдельного вопроса. Но на практике switch даст результат не хуже.

Comment: Попробуйте способ 3 так `static const MY_FN01 array[] = { [] () {/*fn0*/} , /*fn1*/, /*fn2*/};` думаю тут лямды прокатят, а вот с `[this]` прийдется помучатся, наверно обьявить MY_FN01 как closure либо добавить параметр.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае с `enum` однозначно делайте `switch`.

Во-первых, всем программерам понятно, а во-вторых -- быстрее не бывает.

Как для 30, так и для  300 (и даже 2300 (более не проверял)) с небольшими "дырами" в значениях `case`, по крайней мере `gcc`,  делает таблицу адресов меток, выбирает по индексу из нее адрес метки и делает `jmp` на нее.

Comment: > и даже 2300 - лексический анализатор? :)